# BASH: How to get X & Y lines from a file (1-liner)

Tags: bash

I have some output and I would like to get lines 1 and 7. As a stream of output we could stream it with 2 different moduli. But, I digress.

I could easily do this with a for loop but I wonder if there is a more functional / 1-line approach to this:

Here is the data I am working with (I want the URL and the content type):

```
--2019-02-01 01:02:19--  https://artifactory/artifactory/BIF-Releases/com/foo/bif/eventlog/maven-metadata.xml.md5
Reusing existing connection to :443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Server: nginx/1.12.2
  Date: Fri, 01 Feb 2019 09:02:33 GMT
  Content-Type: application/x-checksum
  Content-Length: 32
  Connection: keep-alive
  X-Artifactory-Id: d111c347124a8603:2a97a6e1:1681a62df25:-8000
  Last-Modified: Fri, 01 Feb 2019 09:02:33 GMT
--
--2019-02-01 01:02:19--  https://artifactory/artifactory/BIF-Releases/com/foo/bif/eventlog/maven-metadata.xml.sha1
Reusing existing connection to artifactory:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Server: nginx/1.12.2
  Date: Fri, 01 Feb 2019 09:02:33 GMT
  Content-Type: application/x-checksum
  Content-Length: 40
  Connection: keep-alive
  X-Artifactory-Id: d111c347124a8603:2a97a6e1:1681a62df25:-8000
  Last-Modified: Fri, 01 Feb 2019 09:02:33 GMT
```

The output I would want is just:

```
--2019-02-01 01:02:19--  https://artifactory/artifactory/BIF-Releases/com/foo/bif/eventlog/maven-metadata.xml.md5
  Content-Type: application/x-checksum
--2019-02-01 01:02:19--  https://artifactory/artifactory/BIF-Releases/com/foo/bif/eventlog/maven-metadata.xml.sha1
Content-Type: application/x-checksum
```

Comment: Use `grep -E '^[[:blank:]]*(--|Content-Type)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try to select some content:

```
grep -E "https://|Content-Type:"
# Or when you want to remove the date
grep -Eo "(https://|Content-Type:).*"
```

Comment: It's slow, but it works. Bonus for knowing I would want to drop the date :)

Answer (score 1):

To get lines 1 and 7:

```
sed -n -e 1p -e 7p
```

You probably also want to terminate early:

```
sed -n -e 1p -e '7{p; q;}'
```

or

```
sed -n -e 1p -e 7p -e 7q
```

Comment: all 3 of these solutions stop on the first occurance. :-/

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno They print lines 1 and 7, as asked

Comment: But only once. Maybe I wasn't clear that it needed to print them in a series. If you take the original input of the question you don't get a series. Would love to know if that can be done with sed. Honestly, I assumed it would

Answer (score 1):

Lines 1 and 7:

```
awk 'NR == 1 || NR == 7'
```

Comment: Only produces the first result: 
` awk 'NR == 1 || NR == 7' 50.log 
--2019-02-01 01:02:15--  https://artifactory/artifactory/BIF-Releases/archetype-catalog.xml
  Content-Type: application/xml`